# What is the idiomatic means of organizing this code the "rails way"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

Within our Rails app, I have several webhooks, called by external services (namely PayPal IPN, Mailgun and Pusher). Currently, each type has it's own controller + necessary routes, for example:

```
post 'jobs/:job_id/comments/reply' => 'mailgun#incoming_email_comment'
post '/webhook' => 'pusher#webhook'
post '/paypal/ipn', :to => 'paypal#ipn', :as => :paypal_ipn
```

Is there a cleaner, more "rails way" to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For example `post '/webhook' => 'pusher#webhook'`

pushers_controller.rb

```
class Pushers <ApplicationController
  def webhook
    ....
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :pushers do
  collection do
    post 'webhook'
  end
end
```

now you can get url for that route like this

```
webhook_pushers_path
```

or

```
link_to 'some text', webhook_pushers_path
```

As you can see, now you don't need write url by hands. Rails automatically creates it using name of your controller and your action.
You can read more there http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions